# Rank of matrix - with more information (python)

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, rank

I'm working on a specific class of n-square matrices where the rank is n when n is even, and n-1 when n is odd and I would like to understand why.

numpy.linalg.rank was useful to notice this fact; however, to understand why it happens I would like to have a non-zero linear combination of my lines - or columns - that sum to all-zeros.

I checked how numpy.linalg.rank works and it seems that it won't work (or I did not understood what I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition))

I have no idea how do to that. Is this question too specific so that no existing function does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) or null space. You can get one basis of it with [scipy.linalg.null_space](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html)